# The volume of the “unit ball” in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with respect to the cut norm

Tags: geometry, convex-polytopes, mg.metric-geometry, co.combinatorics

This question is inspired by the question “[*ε*-nets with respect to the cut norm](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53542/epsilon-nets-with-respect-to-the-cut-norm)” by the user Aaron, which had been reposted to [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/epsilon-nets-with-respect-to-the-cut-norm).

The *cut norm* ||*A*||<sub>C</sub> of a matrix *A*=(*a*<sub>*ij*</sub>)∈ℝ<sup>*m*×*n*</sup> is defined as the maximum of |∑<sub>*i*∈*I*,*j*∈*J*</sub>*a*<sub>*ij*</sub>| over the subsets *I*⊆{1,…,*m*} and *J*⊆{1,…,*n*}.  The “unit ball” in ℝ<sup>*m*×*n*</sup> with respect to the cut norm is the convex polytope *P*(*m*, *n*) = {*A*∈ℝ<sup>*m*×*n*</sup>: ||*A*||<sub>C</sub>≤1}.  Let *V*(*m*, *n*) be the volume of this polytope *P*(*m*, *n*).

Since *P*(*m*, *n*) contains [0, 1/*mn*]<sup>*m*×*n*</sup>, we have that *V*(*m*, *n*) ≥ 1/(*mn*)<sup>*mn*</sup>.  In other words, (*V*(*m*, *n*))<sup>1/*mn*</sup> ≥ 1/*mn*.

**Question**.  Is this lower bound on (*V*(*m*, *n*))<sup>1/*mn*</sup> tight up to a constant factor?  In other words, does there exist a constant *c*>0 such that for every *m*,*n*≥1, it holds that (*V*(*m*, *n*))<sup>1/*mn*</sup> ≤ *c*/*mn*?

This lower bound is indeed tight up to a constant factor if one of *m* and *n* is bounded by a constant.  This can be shown as follows.  In [an answer on cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/epsilon-nets-with-respect-to-the-cut-norm/4636#4636), I gave a sketch of a proof that *V*(1, *n*) = (2*n*)!/(*n*!)<sup>3</sup>.  Using this, we have that *V*(*m*, *n*) ≤ (*V*(1, *n*))<sup>*m*</sup> = ((2*n*)!)<sup>*m*</sup>/(*n*!)<sup>3*m*</sup>.  By using [Stirling’s formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we obtain that there exists an absolute constant *d*>0 such that for every *m* and *n*, it holds that (*V*(*m*, *n*))<sup>1/*mn*</sup> ≤ *d* min{1/*m*, 1/*n*}.

A positive answer to this question improves the lower bound on Aaron’s question to match the upper bound up to a constant factor.

Answer (score 3):

A standard argument (Lemma 3.1 [here](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~naor/homepage%2520files/cutnorm.pdf)) shows that the cut-norm is 4-equivalent to the operator norm from $\ell_{\infty}^m$ to $\ell_1^n=(\ell_\infty^n)^*$. Therefore the volume you ask is almost the same (up to a factor $4^{mn}$) as the volume of the unit ball in the  projective tensor product $\ell_{\infty}^m \otimes_\pi \ell_\infty^n$. This is exactly [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60062/volume-of-the-unit-ball-of-the-banach-space-ell-1n-otimes-epsilon-ell-1n/60175#60175) (at least for $m=n$), and I gave an answer saying basically that (from general theorems) your lower bound on $V(m,n)^{1/mn}$ is sharp up to a logarimthic factor.

I guess this logarithm is not necessary, but I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Although I have to admit that most results referred to in your other answer are over my head, I will try (hopefully in a few weeks) to understand at least part of it.

Comment: I see you are interested in quantum complexity, so maybe a source is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.2264. We apply a more sophisticated version of the argument to a problem in quantum information, and we introduce all the material we need in Appendices.